# Spring Boot Java config with Spring Security: How do I configure to use FilterBasedLdapUserSearch and BindAuthenticator?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I am moving from an older version of Spring Security using XML to Spring Boot Security with Java config instead of the old XML config. I have the latest version of Spring Boot `1.3.5.RELEASE` as of about a week ago.

My current XML code uses a `FilterBasedLdapUserSearch` and a `BindAuthenticator` to help find and authenticate the user. This is needed because the LDAP is quite complex so the standard basic spring security settings will not find the user. My settings are letting me successfully login to LDAP, (I know that works because if I change the username or password I get an authentication error), but that is as far as it goes using the below code and doesn't return any user data. I need to get the user data from LDAP to know that they are a legitimate user.

I have searched online for tutorials and examples for this, but have not found anything that helps. There is a lot out there, but most of it references the basic example and does not address the advanced LDAP setup.

Can someone point me in the right direction, please? Any tutorials or examples out there that address this?

Here is my existing XML for LDAP:

```
<beans:bean id="initialDirContextFactory" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldapIpAddress:port" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="dc=hostName,dc=com" />
    <beans:property name="userDn" value="userDNHere" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="passwordHere" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref local="ldapBindAuthenticator" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref local="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ldapBindAuthenticator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:ref local="initialDirContextFactory" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0">
        <beans:value></beans:value>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1">
        <beans:value>userNameSearchHere</beans:value>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2">
        <beans:ref local="initialDirContextFactory" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="searchSubtree">
        <beans:value>true</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

My current Java config is here:

```
@Configuration
 protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

     @Autowired
     public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
         lcs.setUserDn("userDHHere");
         lcs.setPassword("passwordHere");
         lcs.setUrl("ldapIpAddress:port/dc=hostHere,dc=com");
         lcs.setReferral("follow");
         lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
         auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
                .contextSource(lcs)
                .userSearchBase("ouBaseHere")
                .userSearchFilter("userNameSearchHere")
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

The answer was simpler than thought, but took some searching to get it.

The formatting of the Java config was wrong. Once I corrected it to be as below it works fantastic. Hopefully this helps someone else get their LDAP working correctly.

See above for incorrectly formatted Java config.

Here is the corrected Java config:
    @Configuration
 protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

```
 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
     lcs.setUserDn("userDHHere");
     lcs.setPassword("passwordHere");
     lcs.setUrl("ldapIpAddress:port");
     lcs.setReferral("follow");
     lcs.setBase("dc=hostHere,dc=com");
     lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
     auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource(lcs)
            .userSearchBase("ouBaseHere")
            .userSearchFilter("userNameSearchHere")
    }
}
```

With that solved I have been able to add a custom authoritiesPopulator to get roles from a database based on the LDAP submitted username. To do use a custom Authorities Populator to the following:

```
@Autowired
CustomAuthoritiesPopulator customAuthoritiesPopulator;

 @Autowired
 public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
     LdapContextSource lcs = new LdapContextSource();
     lcs.setUserDn("userDHHere");
     lcs.setPassword("passwordHere");
     lcs.setUrl("ldapIpAddress:port");
     lcs.setReferral("follow");
     lcs.setBase("dc=hostHere,dc=com");
     lcs.afterPropertiesSet();
     auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource(lcs)
            .userSearchBase("ouBaseHere")
            .userSearchFilter("userNameSearchHere")
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(customAuthoritiesPopulator);
    }
}
```